# useEffect hook does not rerender an element

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend

I have an issue with useEffect, expect it to re render grid of elements, when on of the elements in this grid was deleted and a variable that contains data of that elements was changed, use effect refers to this variable so I expect it to re render grid where it placed.

```
const TasksView = ({current, tasksViewTriggered, cancelModals, addTaskToNote}) => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])

  const onAddTask = () => {
    addTaskToNote(current.id, '', false)
  }

  const onCancel = () => {
    cancelModals()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('current was changed')
    if (current) {
      setTasks(current.tasks)
    }
  }, [current, tasksViewTriggered])

  return (
    <div className={`tasks-modal ${tasksViewTriggered ? '' : 'invisible'}`}>
      <div className='taskModalContent'>
        <div className="tasks-grid">
          {tasks.length === 0 ? (<p className='center'>No tasks to show</p>) : (
            tasks.map(task => <Task task={task} key={task.id}/>)
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className='modalFooter'>
        <a href='#!' onClick={onCancel} className='btn btn-red'>
          Close
        </a>
        <a href='#!' onClick={onAddTask} className='btn btn-green'>
          Add Task
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

TasksView.propTypes = {
  current: PropTypes.object,
  tasksViewTriggered: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  cancelModals: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  addTaskToNote: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  current: state.note.current,
  tasksViewTriggered: state.note.tasksViewTriggered
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {cancelModals, addTaskToNote}
)
(TasksView);
```

Current value changes on task deletion and I expect this page to be re rendered after, but it does not happen.

Comment: Rather than snippets of code, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on codesandbox ? So I can run and check.

Comment: Sorry, I a novice in web development, I do not know how to use codesandbox propperly, but I can share full project on my github, cause it is my personal app created for learning purposes. https://github.com/shurankain/planning-tool

Comment: current && tasksViewTriggered have not changed both;

Comment: No, even when I delete tasksViewTriggered  it changes nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('current was changed')
    if (current) {
      setTasks(current.tasks)
    }
  }, [current.tasks, tasksViewTriggered])
```

be sure current will not be null